# How to return an array of IDs from stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that should return an array of ids, depending on the result of a `SELECT` query. How can I do this in SQL Server?

Here is my stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[PS_testGar] 
    @CODE_B,
    @ids OUTPUT
AS 
BEGIN  
   SELECT @ids = code_gar
   FROM  [dbo].[GARANTIE]
   WHERE CODE_B= @CODE_B
END
```

Comment: remove the "@ids = ". SQL Server will natively return the list of IDs. What language are you going to call this from?

Comment: Do you really need an output parameter? If so you will need a user defined table type. The simpler approach is to simply have the select statement in your procedure and have that be the resultset.

Comment: @Jeremy i'll call it from a WCF service. i removed the"@ids =" , how should i declare the output param ?

Comment: I wouldn't use an output parameter for this. It is more complicated than it needs to be.

Comment: there is no output parameter. here is a simple example of reading data from .net. you could use an ORM too. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ado-net-code-examples

Comment: @SeanLange from the side of my WCF service, how should i get that resultset?

Comment: read the documentation link I sent you. There are many .NET technologies for reading data from sql server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for an output parameter here. This is what your procedure should look like.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[PS_testGar] 
(
    @CODE_B int --or whatever your datatype is
) AS  
BEGIN  
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT code_gar
    FROM  [dbo].[GARANTIE]
    WHERE CODE_B = @CODE_B
END
```

Comment: How to handle that resultset from my wcf service that is calling this SP ?

Comment: You would use ExecuteReader. Look at the link Jeremy posted in the comments above. It provides several examples.